# combination sum from predefined set with the target value

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have the following code. I need all the combinations of numbers from that array whose sum is the target which is 100000. The problem is that the below solution doesn't contain the following pair `20000 40000 40000` . This is because for each recursion, I take out the number (LOOK at the `filter` functionality). If I don't have `filter` , then maximum call stack exceeded happens.

So the final mission is to have all the combinations of numbers whose sum is target, each combination should have only 3 numbers, and `0` also participates.

Any idea how to fix it ?

```js
function subsetSum(numbers, target, partial) {
  var s, n, remaining;

  partial = partial || [];

  // sum partial
  s = partial.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);

  // check if the partial sum is equals to target
  if (s === target && partial.length === 3) {
    console.log("%s=%s", partial.join("+"), target)
  }

  if (s >= target) {
    return; // if we reach the number why bother to continue
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    n = numbers[i];
    remaining = numbers.filter(num => num != n);
    subsetSum(remaining, target, partial.concat([n]));
  }
}

subsetSum([0, 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000, 90000], 100000);
```

Comment: do you have the wanted result as well?

Comment: *"a pair"*: I suppose you mean triple(t)? I suppose you are only interested in sums of three?

Comment: Not at hand. Just in mind. There should be more than 40 entries I think, so I can't post it. The idea is simple: each combination should contain 3 numbers, the sum of each combination should be target, and combinations should contain duplicates

Comment: @trincot yes.. That's why i have `partial.length === 3`

Comment: OK, but "pair" means two. It is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that it is because you filter out the selected number that you can't get the following output

```
2000 4000 4000
```

When you take the filtering out, you will get a stack overflow, because you didn't stop the recursion when `partial` has a length of 3. So recursive calls that keep adding 0 to `partial` will never stop recursing... as they never lead to exceeding the target.

So add that to the "base case":

```js
function subsetSum(numbers, target, partial) {
  var s, n, remaining;

  partial = partial || [];

  // sum partial
  s = partial.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);

  // check if the partial sum is equals to target
  if (s === target && partial.length === 3) {
    console.log("%s=%s", partial.join("+"), target)
  }

  if (s >= target || partial.length === 3) {
    return; // if we reach the number or maximum length don't bother to continue
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    n = numbers[i];
    subsetSum(numbers, target, partial.concat([n]));
  }
}

subsetSum([0, 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000, 90000], 100000);
```